# Execute action based on a time event in rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Sorry, I am starting working with rails again and I am not even sure how to look for this question so apologies if this has been answered before, I couldn't find a clear answer.

I am building a Telegram bot using the telegram-bot-rb gem which I built before in plain ruby which is running nicely on my desktop. I wanted to use webhooks so I am migrating the code to rails and hosting it on Heroku.

The bot allows you to create events and shares it with friends who can join a given event so I have currently a model for the user, for the event and another one to join both of them to know who joined what meeting.

The issue is that one of the features is that the bot will notify you before a given amount of minutes has passed, defined in your settings and also, every meeting will be deleted after a given amount of time has passed from the start time of the meeting.

I would like to know how could be accomplished this in rails? Each meeting has the start time an each user has a notification time so basically, I would need a way to check if the time from now to the start of the meeting is below the notification time in settings. Is there a way to make this happen when the time is reached or should I have something running in the background as I do with the current version of the bot?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: _"make this happen when the time is reach[ed]"_ implies that something has to be running in the background.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve it using rake task.
You can specify at what time rake task should run. For more info you can see: 
https://railsguides.net/how-to-generate-rake-task/

Comment: _"You can specify at what time rake task should run"_ – how?